# Salvar caminho completo no banco ou apenas o nome com a extensão?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Nos sistemas que costumava a desenvolver antigamente, eu costumava a salvar o caminho completo do arquivo no banco de dados .

Exemplo:

`c:\xampp\htdocs\teste\imagens\post_44\stack_overflow.png`

// Tabela de imagens

```
imagem 
 - id = 1
 - imagem = imagens/post_44/stack_overflow.png
 -post_id = 44
```

Depois, quando passei a utilizar frameworks, passei a colocar apenas o nome do arquivo com a extensão no registro (e os outros dados pego de acordo com a consulta no banco de dados).

```
image
  - id = 1
  - image = stack_overflow.png
  - post_id = 44
```

No caso, eu faço isso porque desenvolvo com o Framework no PHP, e ele me facilita na hora de  "montar" o caminho dessa imagem.

Mas, em se tratando de outros casos, como em sistemas feitos "na mão", qual dessas é a melhor forma de armazenar um nome de arquivo no banco de dados (levando também em consideração performance e manutenção)?

Comment: Sou contra salvar o path, já imaginou se por algum motivo você precise renomear a pasta dos arquivos na aplicação?

Comment: Marcaram para fechar. Pode até ser que seja meio opinático, mas é um problema que muitos iniciantes podem passar por ele.

Comment: Não vejo motivos para fechar esta pergunta. É perfeitamente possível listar os pontos positivos e negativos de cada opção. Não é só questão de opinião.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Na minha opinião o que tornaria mais fácil para manutenção seria armazenar apenas o **nome.extensão;**

- Vamos analisar um pequeno caso:

  Vocês resolvem modificar bruscamente o sistema atual, mudando diversas coisas, inclusive o destino dos arquivos, em fim... seria muito mais fácil alterar o caminho dos arquivos somente em um lugar não é?

  Imagine você alterar registro por registro no banco de dados para os novos caminhos, seria um trabalho desnecessário; lembrando que essa é uma opinião pessoal.
- Em questão de performance, não creio que mudaria muita coisa
  armazenar o caminho inteiro vs somente nome do arquivo (não posso
  confirmar ou dar certeza dessa informação).